# What would be the appropriate font-family CSS targeting both the iOS 7 and Android font?

Tags: android, ios, css, fonts, font-family

I'm creating an universal HTML5 app for iOS and Android, which is a backup to show a client if the native ones get delayed. In just a margin of the time I need for the native ones I could create a HTML5 version. However, to get a more distinctive look between Android and iOS I would like to target the correct font-families.

While iOS uses `Helvetica neue (lighter/font-weight: 100)`, Android uses `Roboto (Light/Font-weight:300)`.

Now I'm seeking the correct way to target them both in a single CSS stylesheet. 
I'm unsure whether this would be enough/correct, I guess not.

`Font-family: font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, Helvetica Neue Light, Roboto-light`.

Thanks!

*Since Roboto is default installed on Android and Helvetica neue default on iOS 7, webfonts aren't necessary.*

Comment: That would work if Helvetica Neue Light isn't installed on Android, which it very probably isn't. It's simple to test, have you tried it?

Comment: Well, I don't have an iPhone nearby at the moment and no SDK live, so I can't test that actually. Only got my Nexus 5 (android) in my pocket. However, I'm sure that `HelveticaNeue-light` or `Helvetica neue light` exist, but not sure whether Roboto-light exists. I've always got Roboto light via Font-weight, but using font weight also affects the Helvetica fonts. Therefor I'm looking for a universal solution to target 'em both. That what it makes it a bit harder. Or I'm overlooking something.